# dpkg returns an error code (1)

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, jupyter

After doing this

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

I get this error message.

```
[EnableNBExtensionApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[EnableNBExtensionApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--sys-prefix'
dpkg: error processing package jupyter-nbextension-jupyter-js-widgets (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jupyter-nbextension-jupyter-js-widgets
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am new Ubuntu user. I seriously don't know how did this happen. Please do not downvote this. This is not a duplicate, any of the previous solutions on this site were not useful. I also googled the error message but the solutions did not help.

Comment: Please specify your Ubuntu version. I can't reproduce this on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Did you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`? (add output to the question if you have any errors in the output).

Comment: @N0rbert actually it is fixed now. I manually deleted broken packages from ```dpkg/info```.